# Can't find the right max Value in my Array loop

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

So my professor gave us this project to read a text file and find the max value, min value, sum. But for some reason when I write the for loop to find the max value it returns a number thats not even in the text file... and I don't know what i did wrong.  I'll attach my code and also the output. Thank you

```
int main () {

ifstream myFile;
char myArray[210];
int i;
int maxVal;
int j;
int minValue;
double myAverage;


myFile.open("Lab #5A Data File.Txt", ios::in | ios::out);

if (myFile.is_open()) {
    cout << "The file is open." << endl; 

    myFile >> noskipws;

while (!myFile.eof()){


for (i=0; i<210; ++i) {


    myFile >> myArray[i];
    cout << myArray[i];
     } 
     myFile >>myArray[i];

    }

maxVal=myArray[0];

for (j=0; j< 210; j++)
    if (myArray[j] > maxVal){

        maxVal=myArray[j];
    }
```

What i get when I run the code :

The file is open.

346 130 982 90  656 117 595
415 948 126 4   558 571 87
42  360 412 721 463 47  119
441 190 985 214 509 2   571
77  81  681 651 995 93  74
310 9   995 561 92  14  288
466 664 892 8   766 34  639
151 64  98  813 67  834 369

The max value is: **51**  <--- I have no idea where this number came from...

Comment: When you're trying to assign the biggest value to the max variable you do: `myArray[i]=maxVal;`. It should be `maxVal = myArray[j];` (As `myArray[j]` is what you are comparing against `maxVal`, not `myArray[i]`)

Comment: Why are you reading numbers as `char`s, instead of `int`s? Why `myFile >> noskipws;`? `51` is the ASCII code of a char `'3'`, which is the first value read from your file.

Answer (score 1):

The `51` is coming from the line:

```
maxVal=myArray[0];
```

In your loop to try to find the biggest element you have:

```
for (j=0; j< 210; j++)
    if (myArray[j] > maxVal){
        myArray[i]=maxVal;
    }
}
```

However this will assign `maxVal` to `myArray[i]` which is not what you want. First of all you need to be assigning `myArray[j]`, not `myArray[i]`, and secondly you need to assign `maxVal` to the bigger value. As it is `maxVal=myArray[0];` is the only time you assign anything to `maxVal`, which is why it is `51` (The ASCII value of the character `3`, which is the first character you read). You need to do something along the lines of:

```
if (myArray[j] > maxVal){
     maxVal = myArray[j];
}
```

I believe you wanted `myArray` to be an `int[]`. Also a better way of doing this is instead of having two for loops and looping until EOF, loop while `myFile >> myArray[i]`:

```
int myArray[210];
int i = 0;
//...
while (myFile >> myArray[i]) {          
    cout << myArray[i] << " ";  
    if (myArray[i] > maxVal) {
        maxVal = myArray[i];
    }
    i++;
}
```

Which for the input file:

```
346 130 982 90 656 117 595 
415 948 126 4 558 571 87 42 
360 412 721 463 47 119 441 
190 985 214 509 2 571 77 81 
681 651 995 93 74 310 9 995 
561 92 14 288 466 664 892 8 
766 34 639 151 64 98 813 67 834 369
```

Returns:

```
995
```

Comment: I don't wanna say anything, but you are comparing char with int: `if (myArray[j] > maxVal){`

You certainly want to add a slice of `atoi()`.

Comment: No mention, of the reason for why the number is `51`, even if it is not present in the input used?

Comment: @Skriptkiddie How is comparison such comparison `char*` with `int`? `myArray` is a `char` array (`char myArray[210];`), making `myArray[j]` a `char`.

Comment: Corrected my comment! You are right, but comparing a char to an int is just as wrong in this case!

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I edited my post to explain that `51` was the ASCII value for `3`, which is the first character the OP is reading

Answer (score -1):

To achieve what you want, you cannot do a comparison like this

```
if (myArray[j] > maxVal){
```

because `myArray[j]` is a char (definitely not holding the integers you are interested in) and maxVal is an int.  This is also the reason you see a 51 - when you try to store an integer into your char, you essentially only read 8 bits from the stream (which results in some value between 0 and 254 which is basically just some 8-bit block from your input stream).

You definitely want something like

```
char myArray[32][210];
```

to be able to read your full integers from the stream into one of these 210 char* slots. 
Then, when comparing (and assigning to maxValue), you need to convert the textual int value to a numeric value, e.g., using atoi().

Comment: "_This is also the reason you see a 51 - when you try to store an integer into your char, you essentially only read 8 bits from the stream (which results in some value between 0 and 254 which is basically just some 8-bit block from your input stream)._" This is wrong. The value you get - is not just "some bits from the stream". You read a `char`. The char equal to value of `'3'`, in this, particular, instance, which corresponds to the ASCII code of `51`.

Comment: W00t? Of course you only read 8 bits from the stream! How many bits do you think a char has, then?